# Undefined symbols for architecture i386, ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I think I've hit a roadblock again, here's the deal:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "CreateRenderer1()", referenced from:
      -[GLView initWithFrame:] in GLView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried nearly all the suggestions that shown up in the auto search when you ask a question:

Adding these libraries to the 'Link Binary With Libraries' tab under 'Build Phases':

```
OpenGLES.framework
QuartzCore.framework
```

Adding all relevant files to the target/compiled sources

Renaming all relevant files with the .m extension to .mm

I'm trying to compile this on the iPhone 5.1 Simulator on Xcode 4.3.2, is there anything glaringly obvious that I'm missing? I have a feeling it's something in the settings but nothing I've tried seems to work =(

Edit:

GLView.h:

```
#import "IRenderingEngine.hpp"
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface GLView : UIView {
    EAGLContext* m_context;
    IRenderingEngine* m_renderingEngine;
    float m_timestamp;
}

- (void) drawView: (CADisplayLink*) displayLink;
- (void) didRotate: (NSNotification*) notification;

@end
```

GLView.mm:

```
#import <OpenGLES/EAGLDrawable.h>   
#import "GLView.h"
#import "mach/mach_time.h"
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h> // <-- for GL_RENDERBUFFER only

@implementation GLView

+ (Class) layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        CAEAGLLayer* eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) super.layer;
        eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
        m_context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

        if (!m_context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:m_context]) {
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }

        m_renderingEngine = CreateRenderer1();

        [m_context
         renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER
         fromDrawable: eaglLayer];

        m_renderingEngine->Initialize(CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame));

        [self drawView: nil];
        m_timestamp = CACurrentMediaTime();

        CADisplayLink* displayLink;
        displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self
                                                  selector:@selector(drawView:)];

        [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                          forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(didRotate:)
         name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) didRotate: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    m_renderingEngine->OnRotate((DeviceOrientation) orientation);
    [self drawView: nil];
}

- (void) drawView: (CADisplayLink*) displayLink
{
    if (displayLink != nil) {
        float elapsedSeconds = displayLink.timestamp - m_timestamp;
        m_timestamp = displayLink.timestamp;
        m_renderingEngine->UpdateAnimation(elapsedSeconds);
    }

    m_renderingEngine->Render();
    [m_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

IRenderingEngine.hpp

```
enum DeviceOrientation {
    DeviceOrientationUnknown,
    DeviceOrientationPortrait,
    DeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
    DeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientationFaceUp,
    DeviceOrientationFaceDown,
};

// Creates an instance of the renderer and sets up various OpenGL state.
struct IRenderingEngine* CreateRenderer1();

// Interface to the OpenGL ES renderer; consumed by GLView.
struct IRenderingEngine {
    virtual void Initialize(int width, int height) = 0;    
    virtual void Render() const = 0;
    virtual void UpdateAnimation(float timeStep) = 0;
    virtual void OnRotate(DeviceOrientation newOrientation) = 0;
    virtual ~IRenderingEngine() {}
};
```

Comment: Do you have GLKit.framework added to your project?

Comment: Can you show the code where you init the view?

Comment: To the first question, nope, I'll edit the view in the main question now!

Comment: Either your IRenderingEngine isn't added to the target, or it can't find the implementation. Are the methods implemented anywhere?

Comment: *Facepalm* Alright, I somehow deleted those, and wasted a bit if time trying to debug this problem, I'll redo them and see what happens next!

Comment: Ok, I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IRenderingEngine implementation isn't being found by the compiler. Either the implementation is missing or the files aren't added to the target correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Although I fixed it, I never really understood how the files 'deleted' themselves, today, I found the answer:

If you rename any subfolders in the Finder manually, XCode will still point to the old path path, which is now invalid.

To fix this, I had right click on the invalid group folder, then, in the file inspected to the right, then click on an obscure tiny little box which lets me manually set the path again!